# The system cannot find the path specified (ndk_build.cmd)

Tags: android

I am a new member, and I begin to develop android with c++, using the Eclipse IDE. But get a message

> "C:\Android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd"
>
> The system cannot find the path specified

when build my first project.

But it exists correct directory.

**Please help me fix this, I sincerely thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to configure your ndk with Eclipse

For this Please follow this below specified steps.

Rigth Click on your project and select **Properties -> Builders->New->Program->OK**

In that in Main Tab specifiy the Location means click on File system and select "**C:\Android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd**" File and select your project work speace. and click ok

Then it will be configured..!

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
But it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"C:\\Android\\ndk\\ndk-build.cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
But it's still not fixed. 
It contains \\ because I write wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try to go to **Window->Preferences->Android->NDK** and fix the NDK path