# Android NDK The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

This is a follow up question to this question:

[The system cannot find the path specified (ndk_build.cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669117/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-ndk-build-cmd)

I got the same problem - I have extracted the NDK folder, set the path in Eclipse menu: Window->Preferences->Android->NDK, but I keep getting the error "The system cannot find the path specified ". Of course the path does exist. I tried using a builder but it gave me the same result for that new builder.

Even if I go to the NDK folder via CMD and try to run it directly, cmd prompts me the same message "The system cannot find the path specified". But it's right there...

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the problem.

The message "The system cannot find the path specified" does not refer to ndk_build.cmd file itself. When checking out the content of the file, I discovered it's actually a script which is trying to find a directory inside the NDK folder which was missing. And why was it missing? Since it turned out to be an NDK for 64 bit operating system which I used on a different computer and this was a 32 bit operating system.

After downloading a 32 bit version of NDK and combining with the suggestion in my linked question of defining a builder for the project, it finally worked.